# SP 2010 - User Email Alerts without SP Access

Tags: 2010, email, alert

Hoping for some insight, is it possible to set up users to get email alerts from a list and somehow stop them from being able to actually see anything on the actual SharePoint site?

I tried the route of not giving the users site permission and setting them up with email alerts, but they don't get anything after the initial "set up" email, so my current theory is they need some sort of permission to actual receive the emails, based on re-doing the alert, asking them to check their spam/junk folders. (however if that is wrong, feel free to correct me).

Essentially, without getting into too much detail, I'm setting up an attendance log, and the goal is to have specific users from specific teams get an email alert when someone on their team calls out and is put down on the list, but we don't want them to have full access to the list of people who have called out for the day

Unfortunately, I'm not at all involved with our Company IT, so I'm sort of out of my element here, but I figure if I at least know this is possible, and how, I can kindly communicate that to our SP IT group for their assistance/rescue, hah.

Edit 1: Cant believe I didnt mention this in my original post, but I dont have access to SP Designer, and cannot get access to it (and IT wont pick it up)

Comment: Are you able to deploy custom solutions?

Comment: (Not an answer, I just can't comment on my post as it made a "new" account when I finished registration..) @jpollar Honestly, I have no idea. I would assume probably not as most technology related items in the company I work for are either extremely dated, or pretty bare-bones. I'm open to any possible ideas if it means I can throw something at IT and see if I can get something to stick, I just wasn't sure how feasible my general idea was and wanted to get some insight before I make a fool of myself to our SP IT group, hah.

Comment: Do you have access to SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio?

Comment: I do not. I know our SP IT team refuses to use SP Designer (or allow us to use it "unsupported", i.e. no internal IT support) but no idea about Visual at the moment (I'm leaning towards probably not).

Comment: You're pretty much screwed then...

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility of receiving an alert on item if you don't have permission on it. But what you could do is to create an WF. Have a list when item is created WF starts and sends an email to whoever you need. You might have some auxiliary list with the email recipients here to achieve your full requirement.

Comment: Agreed, @Mark Saradis correct a workflow can email anyone, even those outside your organization, if you so desire

Comment: I figured that might be the case. Is it possible to set up a permissions group that would only allow a user to receive email alerts, but not be able to see anything on the site? Assuming I could get WF functional (as I mentioned to jpollar, we dont use SP Designer, and I am doubtful of Studio being used either) would it be able to show what's in the entry? We're using the alerts to show select people who called out on their team for work flow management, but we dont want them to have access to see everyone who called out